# Cocoa Touch animation delaying command

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, animation, iphone-sdk-3.2

What is the command of delaying an action to fade in an image?

Comment: You don't want an "xCode delaying command," you want to know how to do it in Cocoa Touch, the framework you're coding in, or possibly in Objective-C, the language you're writing your code in. Xcode is an integrated development environment (IDE). You can develop iOS apps, Mac apps, or most anything with C, C++, Objective-C, Java, AppleScript, Python, or Ruby, and with the appropriate plugins, C#, Haskell, D, Fortan, Ada, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I find the new block-based animation methods on UIView pretty simple to work with:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview

You could do something like

```
UIImageView *yourPic;  // assume it exists
yourPic.opacity = 0.0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^
{
    yourPic.opacity = 1.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Delaying the action u can do in AppDelegation, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
          [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2];
```

For Fade in and Fade out of Image. u can use custom methods for Fade and fade out

Better you could see this post http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/fade-transition-fade-images-in-and-out.html

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want

```
+ (void)setAnimationDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
```

Use it like this (non-block based animations):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:1.5];
myImage.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```